# How to install USB-to-Ethernet Adapter on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ethernet, usb

I am having problems installing a USB-to-Ethernet (model HB-T66) on my HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 v2 server (Intel Xeon) running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

In Device Manager, the device appears at "Other Devices" as "USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor" and the icon contains an exclamation mark indicating it was not properly installed.

Windows won't find the driver online and,since the adapter is a cheap chinese device, there is not available driver for download on the web.

Is there any way to install this kind of device?

[image: device picture]

Comment: You'll need to use a PCIe NIC instead. They're cheap, and they will prove to be much more stable and well-performing in the long run.

Comment: @EEAA well, there are some deployments which use every PCIe port on the motherboard (storage server comes to mind first), so actually I'd recommend a newer USB adapter instead of PCIe

Comment: @Anubioz - A real NIC's adaptor will have it's own CPU to do all the offload and calculation it's no way comparable to a USB plug. For home it's another story, had to buy 2 to find one working on a 2012R2, but cost like 10$, so no worry. (but I would not run a production server off that NIC)

Comment: @yagmoth555, I'm just saying that it's a mistake to treat everyone who asks about something you've never seen yourself in your work as a home-user noobs. Look at this [undeniably enterprise-only supermicro motherboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X10DRD-L.cfm) - it has only one PCI-e slot and god I know a thousand things i'd better use it for (especially since any server motherboard has dual+ Ethernet port already).If I need a third LAN (f.e. emergent access), i'd easily take this [Linksys USB-to-LAN](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-USB3GIG/) over PCI-e.

Comment: Real problem is in buying hardware from NoName companies that cease to exist after they sold their stuff - you won't get any drivers for thier products, but not in the USB->LAN technology which is perfectly useful in business environment.

Comment: @Anubioz I agree, will update my answer. As yes you are right such can work. I dont argue that point. My point is buy another's one to see itf it work, dont try to rewrite a driver. What happen if a second tech format that server and got to re-install that in urgency ? if the OP got to play around with some driver and such ? (and BTW, a ML310 is far far away to be a microserver)

Comment: Yes, I agree that buying another adapter from some company that can be trusted to provide support for a reasonable amount of time is the only acceptable solution here. But it doesn't have to be PCI-e as a must...

Comment: I solved the problem. First I installed on a regular Win7/10 machine and the device was correctly identified. Them I copied the drive files from Windows\System32 folder and used them on the server.

Answer (score 2):

As it's not seen natively by the OS, without available/working driver, no.

At the price of such device, please get one 2012R2's ready, will save you headache, and your co-worker headache too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do that without a native driver for windows 8 from the manufacturer of the device.

First, you can try to edit the driver's .inf file as described in [this guide](http://www.getdriver.com/how-to/2410/make-windows-7-drivers-work-windows-8-8-1-inf-modding.html) to add Windows 8 support to existing Windows 7 driver.

If there is no Windows 7 driver available or if modifying the .inf file won't help - the only way to use the device would be via USB pass-through to a Hyper-V/VmWare virtual machine with an older OS version.